# using raw text as table instead of pointer to table

Tags: 4d-database

Are there any structure access methods in 4D that will let you provide a text data type argument to a 4D method that will let you get information about a table?

I've looked at: `Table`, `Table name` but both seem to only take in a table number or a table pointer -- not regular text.

I know I can achieve this by passing in a pointer to a table like this:

`foo(->[someTable])`

But what I want to do is something like this:

`foo("someTable")`

Are there any methods in 4D that will take raw text and return a table pointer?

I'm using 4D v15.3 but could upgrade to v16 if this feature was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct the pointer using text with the command [`Get pointer`](http://livedoc.4d.com/4Dv15-R2/help/Command/en/page304.html).

```
$pointer:=Get pointer("[foo]")
$tableNumber:=Table($pointer)
```